# When testing a react component with jest an imported method is coming as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

While testing a component which imports a pure function from another file, the pure function is coming as undefined during testing

```
    import {constructQueryVariables} from '../file';
    export class MyComponent extends components {
        getActions = () => {
            return {
                action: () => {
                    const queryParams = constructQueryVariables();
                    // uses queryParams in AJAX call and setState on success
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the test file I have simply done the mounting and the component is imported like

```
    import {MyComponent} from '../MyComponent';
```

I expect queryParams variable to contain the returned object from constructQueryVariables, but getting
TypeError: (0 , _file. constructQueryVariables) is not a function

Please note this is happening only during testing

Comment: Could you share more code? Where is the `setFetchMoreVariablesAction` function defined?

Comment: @ChristiaanScheermeijer I have updated the error message. that function is the one that is imported on top

Comment: is [automock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#automock-boolean) enabled?

Comment: @skyboyer I am not sure whether automock is enabled or not, but other exports from the same file are working fine in test case